# Error: Tensorflow BRNN logits and labels must be same size

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have an error like this:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must
be same size: logits_size=[10,9] labels_size=[7040,9]  [[Node:
SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits =
SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Reshape, Reshape_1)]]
```

But I can't find the tensor which occurs this error.... I think it is appeared by size mismatching...

My Input size is `batch_size` * `n_steps` * `n_input`

so, It will be 10*704*100, And I want to make the output

`batch_size` * `n_steps` * `n_classes` => It will by 10*700*9, by Bidirectional RNN

How should I change this code to fix the error?

batch_size means the number of datas like this:

data 1 : ABCABCABCAAADDD...
...
data 10 : ABCCCCABCDBBAA...

And
n_step means the length of each data ( The data was padded by 'O' to fix the length of each data) : 704

And
n_input means the data how to express the each alphabet in each data like this:
A - [1, 2, 1, -1, ..., -1]

And the output of the learning should be like this:
output of data 1 : XYZYXYZYYXY ...
...
output of data 10 : ZXYYRZYZZ ...

the each alphabet of output was effected by the surrounding and sequence of alphabet of input.

```
learning_rate = 0.001
training_iters = 100000
batch_size = 10
display_step = 10
# Network Parameters
n_input = 100 
n_steps = 704 # timesteps
n_hidden = 50 # hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 9 

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_classes])

weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2*n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}
def BiRNN(x, weights, biases):
    x = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(x, perm=[1, 0, 2]))

    # Forward direction cell
    lstm_fw_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
    # Backward direction cell
    lstm_bw_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
    # Get lstm cell output
    try:
        outputs, _, _ = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, x,
                                          dtype=tf.float32)
    except Exception: # Old TensorFlow version only returns outputs not states
       outputs = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, x,
                                    dtype=tf.float32)
    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']
pred = BiRNN(x, weights, biases)
# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_x, batch_y = next_batch(batch_size, r_big_d, y_r_big_d)
        #batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size, n_steps, n_input))
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
       sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        if step % display_step == 0:
            # Calculate batch accuracy
            acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            # Calculate batch loss
            loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            print("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        step += 1
    print("Optimization Finished!")
    test_x, test_y = next_batch(batch_size, v_big_d, y_v_big_d)
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
        sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_x, y: test_y}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first return value of [`static_bidirectional_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_bidirectional_rnn) is a list of tensors - one for each rnn step. By using only the last one in your `tf.matmul` you're losing all the rest. Instead, stack them into a single tensor of the appropriate shape, reshape for the `matmul` then shape back.

```
outputs = tf.stack(outputs, axis=1)
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, (batch_size*n_steps, n_hidden))
outputs = tf.matmul(outputs, weights['out']) + biases['out']
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, (batch_size, n_steps, n_classes))
```

Alternatively, you could use [`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum):

```
outputs = tf.stack(outputs, axis=1)
outputs = tf.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl', outputs, weights['out']) + biases['out']
```

Comment: But I have another problems in "outputs = tf.matmul(outputs, weights['out']) + biases['out']" line.  The error comment is like this : "Dimensions must be equal, but are 9 and 128 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [7040,9], [128,9]."

Comment: Oops fixed. First reshape should be lots * n_hidden, not lots * n_classes